# single mock of object in nested describe functions (jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine

if I have a jasmine spec with nested describe methods, and I want to place a spy on a method, to have it return a specific result, once across all the methods what is the correct approach?  I know I can simply define the spy in the top level method, however, does this mean that some of my tests get the same object?  I don't want changes from one test to be maintained in another, even if it allows code reuse.

so, If I have something like this:

```
describe ('tope level test', function(){ 
   var FOO;

   beforeEach( module ('FooBar') );

   beforeEach( inject (function( _Foo_){
        FOO=_Foo_;
        FOO.bar=jasmine.createSpy('foobar').andReturn("baz");
   }));

    describe('test A', function(){

       if('sub1', function(){
           FOO.newMethod=function() {'this shouldn't exist'};
        });

       if('sub2', function(){
          FOO.newMethod();
       });
 })]);
```

I would think sub2 would be able to access newMethod because sub1 defined it and the beforeEach that defined FOO ran at the start Task A but FOO only, so sub1 and sub2 shared the same FOO.  Is that correct?

Assuming it is correct how could I add a spy at the very top level of describe while also ensuring that the object is generated fresh each time it's used in a test, just with the desired spy each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Object.create() to make new instance of object:

```
describe ('tope level test', function(){ 
  var FOO;

  beforeEach( module ('FooBar') );

  beforeEach( inject (function( _Foo_){
    FOO = Object.create(_Foo_);
    FOO.bar = jasmine.createSpy('foobar').andReturn("baz");
  });

  describe('test A', function(){

   if('sub1', function(){
      FOO.newMethod = function() {'this shouldn\'t exist'};

      expect(FOO.bar).toBeDefined();
      expect(FOO.newMethod).toBeDefined();
    });

   if('sub2', function(){
      expect(FOO.bar).toBeDefined();
      expect(FOO.newMethod).not.toBeDefined();
   });
});
```

Comment: Could you help me understand how this works?  It seems like creating the new object wouldn't change anything, though that is no doubt due to my lack of understanding of jasmine.  I would have thought that since the beforeEach that creates and saves FOO to be run once, before the test A block starts, but not before each of the 'it' functions.  Thus would would have thought even if you defined a new Object it would still be shared across both it functions?  Is there something wrong with my understanding?